# Query for PFInstallation based on what time it is in the timezone

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have a specific need to fetch `PFInstallation` objects (from **Parse.com**) that have **a specific time at their locale / timezone**.

`PFInstallation` objects have a property called `timeZone`, which is a timezone identifier - for instance, `America/Los_Angeles`. What I need though is an **hour offset from UCT**.

So, the question - **how do I query for `PFInstallation` objects where it's 9AM in their timezone**?

Comment: Parse doesn't calculate this anywhere in the `PFInstallation` class so your query would render useless. You have to convert it yourself then cross reference those times with the time zone areas in your `PFInstallation` class